# new Skype 4.1.0.37 on fedora 18

Tags: fedora, skype

Several days ago I've got issue. The Skype cannot connect to the server. Some googling get that I have to uninstall and install new one (last 4.1.0.37).

Current when I try to run Skype - I get the error!

"Process /usr/bin/skype was killed by signal 6 (SIGABRT)"

Please help, how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version is 4.3.0.37.

To install it, you need to visit the [Fedora download page](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=fedora32), and download the rpm. Then open a terminal, type

```
su
```

to become root (and type in the root password), and then navigate to the directory where you downloaded the rpm (the Downloads directory for the current user, probably). Now you can type

```
yum localinstall skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm
```

to install it and all its dependencies. If an old version is installed already, it'll update it.

Comment: Was resolved:

1. I deleted folder /home/myacc/.skype
2. yum remove Skype
3. yum localinstall skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm 

it works for me, I think internal issue in the Skype.